# Color stack switch with current color interferes with vertical list

Tags: color

I would like to use color stacks from the [pdfcol](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcol) package for breakable boxes.

`\pdfcolSwitchStack` switches the stack, but uses black as initial color and not the current color as I need for my application.

There is `\pdfcolSetCurrentColor` which *replaces the topmost entry of the stack by the
current color*. Unfortunately, it also seems to actually set the current color (again)? At least, it interferes with the vertical list in some way (adding a whatsit?).
In several situations, vertical space is added/changed when `\pdfcolSetCurrentColor` is used.

I am looking for a way to switch the color stack taking the current color as topmost entry *without* setting this color again or interfering with the vertical list.

The following MWE displays the problem.

**Version A (not using `\pdfcolSetCurrentColor`):**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}
\usepackage{pdfcol,parskip}

\pdfcolInitStack{mycolstack}

\newbox\mwebox
\newbox\firstbox

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\splitexample}[1]%
  {%
    \setbox\mwebox\vbox%
      {%
        \pdfcolSwitchStack{mycolstack}%
        %\pdfcolSetCurrentColor%------------------------------------------
        \color@begingroup%
          \hsize=11cm\relax%
          #1%
        \color@endgroup%
      }%
    \setbox\firstbox\vsplit\mwebox to 7cm%
    \fbox%
      {%
        \color@begingroup%
        \pdfcolSetCurrent{mycolstack}%
        \box\firstbox%
        \pdfcolSetCurrent{}%
        \color@endgroup%
      }
    \par inter text \par
    \fbox%
      {%
        \color@begingroup%
        \pdfcolSetCurrent{mycolstack}%
        \box\mwebox%
        \pdfcolSetCurrent{}%
        \color@endgroup%
      }
  }%

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\color{blue}

before text

\splitexample{%
  \begin{minipage}{9cm}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item abc
  \end{enumerate}
  \end{minipage}\par
  \lipsum[1]
  {\itshape\bfseries\color{red}
  \lipsum[2]
  }
  \lipsum[3]
}

after text
\end{document}
```

Here, the main color is blue. The color stack `mycolstack` switches to black.

[image]

**Version B (using `\pdfcolSetCurrentColor`):**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}
\usepackage{pdfcol,parskip}

\pdfcolInitStack{mycolstack}

\newbox\mwebox
\newbox\firstbox

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\splitexample}[1]%
  {%
    \setbox\mwebox\vbox%
      {%
        \pdfcolSwitchStack{mycolstack}%
        \pdfcolSetCurrentColor%------------------------------------------
        \color@begingroup%
          \hsize=11cm\relax%
          #1%
        \color@endgroup%
      }%
    \setbox\firstbox\vsplit\mwebox to 7cm%
    \fbox%
      {%
        \color@begingroup%
        \pdfcolSetCurrent{mycolstack}%
        \box\firstbox%
        \pdfcolSetCurrent{}%
        \color@endgroup%
      }
    \par inter text \par
    \fbox%
      {%
        \color@begingroup%
        \pdfcolSetCurrent{mycolstack}%
        \box\mwebox%
        \pdfcolSetCurrent{}%
        \color@endgroup%
      }
  }%

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\color{blue}

before text

\splitexample{%
  \begin{minipage}{9cm}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item abc
  \end{enumerate}
  \end{minipage}\par
  \lipsum[1]
  {\itshape\bfseries\color{red}
  \lipsum[2]
  }
  \lipsum[3]
}

after text
\end{document}
```

Now, the color stack `mycolstack` takes over the main blue color as expected.

**But, note that `1. abc` changed vertical position after inserting `\pdfcolSetCurrentColor`.**

[image]

Is there a way to use the current color for the color stack without altering the vertical list?

Comment: could you write into the text which colors you expect where? And where you get wrong spacing from the whatsits?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The wrong spacings are at the begin of the first box. Take a look at `1. abc`. The colors of Version B are the expected ones.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The MWE contains the `parskip` package to make vertical shifts more obvious. Without it, there is a much smaller shift (but it is there).

Comment: tricky, they seem to be whatsits, (and with xelatex they certainly will be \special's).  But I wonder why you don't have problems with hyperref, it inserts whatsits imho at a quite similar place.  Personally I think that the benefit of correct colors overweight the spacing issues. But perhaps one can make it an option, like the parbox key and then users can choose to activate it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I think there is no hyperref-related stuff at the begin of the breakable box. Labels are smuggled in later, when the box is used inside a tikzpicture. Color settings can also be avoided (not in the current version), but not in combination with color stacks. If nothing comes up to solve the problem, making color stacks an option is an option ;-)

Comment: hm, the extra spacing disappears if I use `\leavevmode \pdfcolSetCurrentColor` in your second example, but I'm not sure that I understand why.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I just checked: In the real application `\leavevmode` makes things worse...

Comment: I suspected this.  Would it work if you do something like the footnoterule: insert a \leavevmode/a box always and then revert the additional spacing?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried a lot of such things meanwhile, but the problem seems to be that enumerate inserts `\parsep` space, because it is not top of the vertical list. I cannot revert this, because a negative `\parsep` displaces all contents which not start with enumerate (or friends).

Comment: I think this must be solved on the latex side. whatsits commands in vmode should set some flag which a directly following list then catches.